# How do I "power slide"?

Tags: borderlands-2

To get the "Blue Sparks" challenge I need to "power slide" into enemies to kill them. Since I've successfully completed the game without ever killing a single enemy in this way, I apparently don't know how to do it.

I have (I think) killed several enemies with the Boost ability in cars and I've got plenty of progress in the run-stuff-over challenge, so what's the trick for this one?

Comment: Granted the fact that I always take gunner seat drastically limits my roadkill stats...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apply the brake while in a turn to power slide.  That's the right bumper on a 360 controller.

This causes the wheels to lose traction, and the vehicle to move sideways.

Power sliding over an enemy - very difficult.

---

"Blue Sparks" is a reference to Mario Kart Wii, where power sliding builds up blue sparks.  These sparks cause you to boost after the power slide is finished.

Power sliding (aka drifting) in other racing games (such as the Burnout series) allows you to corner more sharply.

Comment: Default key is 'G' on PC.

Comment: Ahah. Yeah, that's not something I would have thought to do.

Comment: It is actually possible to power slide while turning only slightly, and not letting go of accelerator, which makes hitting enemies much easier. Still, the best way to farm the challenge is to massively overlevel skags to kill them with one hit.

Comment: Maintaining forward (or reverse) motion was what I was missing.  On the PS3 it's the left joystick that's the accelerator, just keep that pressed forward or pulled back while you simultaneously turn and brake with the right joystick and trigger.  And as Orc JMR said, aim for skags, as they're the easiest prey on playthrough 1.

Answer (score 2):

there's a video tutorial that tells you how to do it

Comment: This would be a better answer if you summarized the process right here in the question.

Comment: See my comment to @AmyB's answer for PS3 tips.